# How do I check for a null value in an object attribute ahead of using reflection to get the value?

Tags: c#

As part of my logging, I'm building out a process where I'm going to dump the values of a custom object.  This object can have null values in it.  However, when I go to dump, I get another exception when I use:

```
string szVarValue = field.GetValue(info).ToString();
```

An example object looks like this:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string firstName 
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string lastName 
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So if the object looks like this:

```
UserInfo ui = new UserInfo();
ui.firstName = "Bob";
ui.lastName = null; // would be null by default, but sample here for visual
```

Then when I go to call the reflection to get the set attributes on like this:

```
            foreach (FieldInfo field in info.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static))
            {

                string szVarName = field.Name;
                string szVarValue = field.GetValue(info).ToString(); // exception here

                if (szVarValue != null || szVarValue != string.Empty)
                    szConfig += szVarName + " = " + szVarValue + "\r\n";

            }
```

But it dumps on any attribute that is null, in this case it would be lastName.  The attribute/field isn't available to look at as far as I can see until I run the reflection against it.  Is there another way to look to see if the attribute/field is null before calling the reflection to get the value?

Comment: The problem is that `field.GetValue(info)` might return `null`, but you're always trying to call `.ToString()` on it... If you just want to check for `null` values, then use `field.GetValue(info) != null`. If you want to check for `null` values and empty strings, use `object value = field.GetValue(info); if (value != null && value != string.Empty)`. No need for any calls to `ToString()`

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks!